# Understanding Raw NETCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I have downloaded .`nc` files (you can see here the .csv format of it RCP4.5 CLOUD COVER ---see image1[image]) from `https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/` (both historical files and RCP scenarios --`RCP 4.5, 6 AND 8.5`). I have browsed the net about how to preprocess them (looked for some tutorials and more direct answers and approach online) but I am still not sure of it. I uploaded the `.nc` files (1 or 2 files) in QGIS and used `gdal2xyz` and found out that each `.nc` file consists of several bands (see image2--[image].

I really want to understand `.nc` file component so I will be able to preprocess it using programming languages like python (maybe)----or if not, be able to understand `.nc` file's  components (at least).

All I want to do is be able to have a `time series data` of  the `average of the whole square grid` or `location` I need with variables such as:

```
Precipitation             Time
```

and other variables available in the `https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/` like temperature, cloud cover etc

Will anyone enlighten me about `.nc` files and how I can pre-process it?

**To download my sample .nc file, please go to this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ok2tVD_iCXe93Q1HYGv1jtyaTIc7wY2N/view?usp=sharing

PS. The image of `.csv` file above is for variable: `"cloud cover"`(RCP4.5 CLOUD COVER)

Comment: If you are new to NetCDF please look through libraries such as xarray or my package nctoolkit on Python. On the terminal use CDO or NCO.

Comment: @RobertWilson I tried to use nctoolkit in python but I keep on getting this "Please install CDO version 1.9.3 or above: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/ or https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cdo" probably because I'm using windows. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @RobertWilson so now I'm trying to use the nctoolkit, but i got this error when i'm trying to calculate the weighted mean: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'weighted' :(

Comment: On Windows you will need the linux subsystem or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by weighted mean. I don't think "weighted" is used anywhere in the nctoolkit code, so can't see what would cause that error. If something is not working it is probably better to raise an issue here: https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit/issues

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi : Did you make any progressing understanding NetCDF files?